# List View With Section Headers

Tags: android

I have a working list view with base adapter.

I have implemented list view with section headers based on this tutorial by Cyril Mottier (2011).
Please look at Method #2: Leverage GONE visibility.

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/

So each row of the list view has a text view that is revealed based on some logic to determine if its a section header.

The problem I am having is on the row which contains an item and section header clicking on the section header is the same as clicking on the row.

I only want the item to be clickable if that is possible.

Diagram

**________________________ROW__________________________**

------------TextView (SECTION HEADER)------------

------------TextView (SOME ITEM)----------------------

**________________________ROW__________________________**

I do not want clicking on TextView Section Header to be the same as clicking the entire row. Only clicking on textView some item can do it but I still wish to use the onItemClickListener. Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
Solution: as described by user Coeffect
Added this in my getView method of the base adapter sub class

```
holder.tvSection.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that might work:

1. Set the section header TextView to not be clickable (`clickable=false`) in the XML.
2. Add a click listener to the section header that doesn't do anything